# Extract only single instance of each word from a list?

Tags: google-sheets

I currently have a table with alchohol name, type and origin which can be found in this [Google Sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V0T8doTMQiLrLE9LKPpRy467cIhRTiDcvzn6te5BGvg/edit?usp=sharing)

This is what the table looks like:

```
Alcohol Name    Alcohol Type    Origin
Jack Daniels    Whisky  USA
Famous Grouse   Scotch  Scotland
Russian Standard    Vodka   Russia
Grants  Scotch  Scotland
Barcardi    Rum Cuba
Black Label Scotch  Scotland
Ciroc   Vodka   France
Southern Comfort    Bourbon USA
Martell Cognac  France
Courvoiser  Cognac  France
Captain Morgans Rum Jamaica
Wray & Nephew   Rum Jamaica
Hennessey   Cognac  France
Ciroc   Whisky  France
```

Effectively, I want something like this:

```
Alcohol Type
Bourbon
Cognac
Rum
Scotch
Vodka
Whisky
```

I suspect it is something to do with `COUNTIF` but I can't seem to get my head around it

Any help would be great

Comment: Put expected result in sheet @Ras

Comment: @Swen Thanks mate, I just created a new column called `Expected Results` in the first tab. I did it manually but looking to automate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(B2:B))
```

[image]

Comment: You legend! It works! Thanks! BTW would this work in other places like Excel sheets? I use both from time to time, if not its cool

Comment: Read about Excel. Try it in Excel :)

Comment: no worries mate. Thanks for you help again!! I accepted your answer too

Comment: Sorry I sound like this, but try is very simple. I mean no harm.

Comment: no worries mate, no offence taken! I accepted the answer and thanks again.